# add libsndfile to a Qt project

Tags: c++, windows, qt, libsndfile

I want to use libsndfile library in a Qt project, then I need to link it but I always get an error :

```
    main.cpp:129: error : undefined reference to `sf_open'
    main.cpp:137: error : undefined reference to `sf_write_short'
```

I tried to add these lines to my .pro

1)
INCLUDEPATH += C:/libsndfile/include
LIBS    += -LC:/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.lib

2)
INCLUDEPATH += C:/libsndfile/include/
LIBS += C:/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.lib

3)
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../libsndfile/lib/ -llibsndfile-1

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../libsndfile/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../libsndfile/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.lib

Can you help me ,please, to link sndfile library correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
LIBS+= -L<PATH TO DIR WITH DLL> -lsndfile-1
```

For example:

```
LIBS+= -LC:/sndfile -lsndfile-1
```

Of course the library itself must be compiled with the compiler you use (mingw?). Don't try to use VS-compiled library with MinGW and vice versa.

Comment: I think that's the answer I was looking for. How do I know where a lib was compiled?
I'm trying to use a third-party library, I have tried almost every combination of linking to the .lib, the .dll and still getting the undefined reference error.